# FOR LOOP Robot Framework variable not found

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, built-in

> I am getting this error while using the For loop in robot framework
> Verify Login Should Fail For Invalid Credentials :: Verification o...
> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:56049/devtools/browser/5e3d951e-ee9f-4b9a-8347-0d4a746ffe57
> Verify Login Should Fail For Invalid Credentials :: Verification o...
> | FAIL | Variable '${item}' not found.
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ DataDrivenCSV Test For Invalid Login Scenarios :: Saucedemo e-comm...
> | FAIL | 1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed 1 test total, 0 passed, 1
> failed

Code used:

```
Logincheck For Invalid Scenarios
[Arguments]  ${invalid_user_credentials}
    For  ${item}  IN  @{invalid_user_credentials}
        Enter Username For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
        Enter Password For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
        Submit Login Form With Credentials
        Wait For Error Message On Login Page For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
    END
```

I am not sure if this is bug in robot framework new version of applying for loop or I did something wrong as ${item} is not global it is local to that loop only why it's throwing error.
Also if I used this style which is deprecated now then I am not getting this error, why?

```
Logincheck For Invalid Scenarios
[Arguments]  ${invalid_user_credentials}
:For  ${item}  IN  @{invalid_user_credentials}
\   Enter Username For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
\   Enter Password For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
\   Submit Login Form With Credentials
\   Wait For Error Message On Login Page For Invalid Logincheck  ${item}
```

can anyone help me in this matter to understand?

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error, it should be uppercase `FOR`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "FOR" instead of "For" , seems issue with that only